# What does this entry "smtp_stream_setup" in my postfix log mean?

Tags: postfix, log-files, logwatch

My logwatch shows me every day lots of these messages from my postfix log. Can anyone explain what it means?

```
    1   Jan  2 14:01:50 interface postfix/smtpd[21465]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
```

Any hint is highly appreciated

Comment: @anx Hm well. Maybe. :-) How can I check this?

Comment: Okay. Found it myself. https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/troubleshooting-problems-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql#postfix And yes I did enable verbose logging some time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this message postfix informs you of the settings in use, whenever a situation occurs where certain timeouts are enforced.

Read the docs here (note the other `smtp_*_timeout` settings):

- http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_data_xfer_timeout
- http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_per_record_deadline

Note that those docs may list other defaults than your distribution, compare your settings with your default using the `-d` flag:

```
postconf smtp_data_xfer_timeout
postconf -d smtp_data_xfer_timeout
```